# Same ID which occurs multiple times with SQL-IN Operator at rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I use the following sql statement:

```
 Keyword.where("id IN (#{params[:keyword_ids]})").order("find_in_set(id, '#{params[:keyword_ids]}')")
```

The Problem at this statement is that if "keyword id" hold the same id more than ones, the call returns it only ones.

But I need the **same number(not fulfilled)** as well as the **same order(which is fulfilled with this statement)** which occurs in the array, independent if the same id occurs more than ones.

How should I change that statement to fix.

Thanks, dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's not a bug, it's a feature ;)

My first recommendation would be to sanitize your input. Passing `params[:keyword_ids]` directly to the database, despite the help that the Rails framework does, is prone to lead to some kind of vulnerability sooner or later.

Secondly, the easiest solution is probably to keep the query as is, convert the results to a map and map the input params to the result.

Sth like

```
keywords = Keyword.where('id IN (?)', checked_keyword_ids)
keyword_map = Hash[keywords.map { |kw| [kw.id, kw] }]
checked_keyword_ids.map { |id| keyword_map[id] }
```